# C++ Qt executable compatible with all windows computers?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have had problems in the past using visual C++, when I ran the executable on other computers it required a .NET framework. I have now started looking at c++ Qt GUI builder and from what I have read C++ doesnt require any additional downloads apart from the executable file to be able to run on other computers, is this true? If I use Qt to build my GUI and send it to other users they will need no other external downloads?

Comment: Yes, portable install is easy with C++. You only need to provide exe file and all needed dll files.

Answer (score 0):

> I have now started looking at c++ Qt GUI builder and from what I have read C++ doesnt require any additional downloads apart from the executable file to be able to run on other computers, is this true?

Not necessarily; see below.

> If I use Qt to build my GUI and send it to other users they will need no other external downloads?

You will potentially need to get redistributables installed on each user machine where this is needed, but this is not a Qt issue, just a generic principle how VS/MSVC and Windows work. However, there is no gentle way around to it in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I can tell you that some of my users need to download the Visual C++ Redistributable package. They would sometimes get a missing "msvcr.dll" error. Very frustrating. I tried including the file with the install, but it was picked up as a virus by some antivirus programs.